# Are there shallow rack cases or bags?

Tags: hardware

I'm looking for a portable 4RU rack case or bag with less than 8 inches depth.  Everything I look at seems to be over a foot deep which makes plugging things in the back a bit of a hassle.

Does such a thing even exist?

Answer (score 1):

Just get one made up.

Most 'guitar shops' have access to a flight case company - they can point you in the right direction.
It wouldn't be hugely expensive to have them rip one of their standard units down to half depth, you'd possibly get it for the same price as a full depth, as the work involved is very similar.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, they do exist, but are somewhat rare. A search for '19" rack shallow' turned up at least one [random example](https://www.thomannmusic.com/thomann_rack_case_4u_shallow.htm). Or you can have one custom-made, this can be done [inexpensively](https://www.roadcasesusa.com/99-dollar-custom-cases/).